# Putting classes in a Hashtable

Tags: java, interface, hashtable

I have a set of classes that implement a certain interface. I have put all those classes in a `Hashtable` `ht` like this:

```
ht.put(str,backend.instructions.ADC.class);
```

But when I call the `get()` function of the hashtable and try to cast the object as the Interface's object, I am getting a `ClassCastException`:

```
           InsInterface4 obj=(InsInterface4) ht.get(str);
```

How can I resolve the same? I have to call functions of the class but, I am not even able to cast properly? What is wrong in this?

Answer (score 3):

Because you are putting a `Class` and you try to get an `Interface4`. If you want to have instances, rather than definitions inside the map, use: `t.put(str, new ADC())`. A few notes:

- You can also use generics to guarantee that you put the correct things at compile time: `Hashtable<String, Interface4>`.
- Prefer `HashMap` to `Hashtable`

Answer (score 1):

`backend.instructions.ADC.class` is a Class, not an instance of that class.

You can do

```
Class<InsInterface4> clazz = (Class<InsInterface4>) ht.get(str);
// if there is a default constructor
InsInterface4 obj = (InsInterface4_ clazz.newInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have put the definition of the class in the table. You need to put actual instances of the class.

```
 backend.instructions.ADC anAdc = new  backend.instructions.ADC();
 someOther.instructions.OTH anOth = new  someOther.instructions.OTH();

 ht.put("adc", anAdc);
 ht.put("oth", anOth);

 InsInterface4 obj=(InsInterface4) ht.get("adc");
```